# How can fix error [System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'gdi32.dll' or one of its dependencies]?

Tags: .net-core, centos, centos7

I build a Application NetCore 3.1 ,it using `System.Drawing.Common.dll` and run on Centos7:

My Setting to publish by vs2019:
[image]

But my Program occur error:

```
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'gdi32.dll' or one of its dependencies. In order to help diagnose loading problems, consider setting the LD_DEBUG environment variable: libgdi32.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I had run install `libgdiplus`, it can't resolve this error:

```
sudo yum install libgdiplus
```

How can fix error [System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load shared library 'gdi32.dll' or one of its dependencies] on Centos 7?

Comment: Didn't try out but maybe will help: https://code-bude.net/2017/05/08/net-core-gdiplus-dll-nicht-gefunden-unter-ubuntu/ The idea is that linux doesn't find a file with DLL extension so a symbolic link is necessary

Comment: I had try [sudo ln -s libgdiplus.so gdiplus.dll], but it error: [ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘gdiplus.dll’: File exists]

Comment: Did you build it on the same box as CentOS7?

Comment: Yes, I publish by vs2019 with setting at Image of my question.